# Empty String on opening self closed tag from rss feed

Tags: android, xml, hyperlink, rss, feed

I've to read a stream from a rss feed on an Android application.
All work fine, but i'm not able to get the complete url, from the  tag, because it's a selfclosed tag

somethings like

This's the xml page (i can't edit it)  [Xml source page](http://www.ilcaleidoscopio.info/menu/ilcaleidoscopio2.xml)

and this is the code to populate to create the single objet that I need

```
String titolo, descrizione, descrizione_breve, img, data, icona;
            Notizia SitoDaAggiungere;

            for (int i = 0; i < nodi.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nodoItem = nodi.item(i);
                if (nodoItem.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element elemento = (Element) nodoItem;

                    titolo = elemento.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();
                    descrizione_breve =    elemento.getElementsByTagName("summary").item(0).getTextContent();

                    descrizione = elemento.getElementsByTagName("content").item(0).getTextContent();
                    img = elemento.getElementsByTagName("pic1").item(0).getTextContent();
                    data = elemento.getElementsByTagName("updated").item(0).getTextContent();
                    icona = elemento.getElementsByTagName("pic").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String link_sito = elemento.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0).getTextContent();   //  <-- no error, but an empty string
                    SitoDaAggiungere = new Notizia(titolo, descrizione, descrizione_breve, data, img, icona, link_sito);

                    InserisciSito(SitoDaAggiungere);
                }

            }
```

Someone can help me?
thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1):

finally I do it!!!
this's the code to get the url

```
String link_sito = elemento.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
```

now I simply use it to create the new objet